# Java new file creation works on local but not on websphere application server

Tags: java, file, websphere, creation

The following code creates a new file in `C:\tmp\JSON\Input` when I run the application in my local:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(new File("\tmp\JSON\Input" ,  "file.json"), request);
```

But when the ear is deployed to the server, I'm not sure where the file is created. I looked for it under `/<root>/tmp/JSON/Input` in the server and it is not there.

Am I doing it right or is there another way to do this? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: are you using servlet ?

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly, WAS is not running on Windows on the servers, and there is no c:. If *nix and allowed, the /tmp directory would be created on the root, but I doubt that is allowed.

There is no simple solution. Talk to the server admins and find out if they provide a directory for temporary files.

Comment: The use of backslashes in the file path string could also be problematic - it would be better code hygiene to use File.separator there, although just switching to a forward slash would also be likely to work (and usually works on Windows as well).